# How to create player turns in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, 2d-games

I am writing this post to get help on passing between players using JQuery. I am currently designing a dominos game with four players. My current version works until the end but it gets extremely laggy by the last four pieces. I have determined that this is due to the recursion in  the  playTurn function. I have tried to use events but that has not worked well for me. My question is if you know how to create a better game loop using JQuery. I would like to finish the basics for this game using JQuery but any suggestions on a better path would be much appreciated. The code is below.

P.S. The game is nowhere near complete but I would very much like to get this problem fixed before proceeding. I am also a beginner to javascript. Thank you for your assistance.

Edit: After some tinkering and help from a stackover flow user, I realized that my addDominoToBoard function in my playTurn function was the main culprit of the lag. Any suggestions on how to better redraw my board. Thank you once again.

```
var makeBoard = function(){
    var totalkeys = [
                        [0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[0,6],
                        [1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],
                        [2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],
                        [3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],
                        [4,4],[4,5],[4,6],
                        [5,5],[5,6],
                        [6,6]
                    ];
    return totalkeys;
}

var randomInt = function(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
}

var makeHand = function(board){
    var hand = [];
    for(x = 0;x<7;x++){
        var ranInt = randomInt(0,board.length);
        var key = board[ranInt];
        hand.push(key);
        board.splice(ranInt,1);
    }
    return hand;
}

var hideItems = function(){
    if($("#player1").hasClass('first')){
        $("#player2").hide();
        $("#player3").hide();
        $("#player4").hide();
    }else if ($("#player2").hasClass('first')){
        $("#player1").hide();
        $("#player3").hide();
        $("#player4").hide();
    }else if($("#player3").hasClass('first')){
        $("#player2").hide();
        $("#player1").hide();
        $("#player4").hide();
    }else{
        $("#player2").hide();
        $("#player3").hide();
        $("#player1").hide();
    };  
}

var loadGame = function(){
    var board = makeBoard();
    var player1Hand = makeHand(board);
    var player2Hand = makeHand(board);
    var player3Hand = makeHand(board);
    var player4Hand = makeHand(board);
    createHands(player1Hand,player2Hand,player3Hand,player4Hand);
    hideItems()

}

var createHands = function(player1Hand,player2Hand,player3Hand,player4Hand){
    for(x = 0; x < player1Hand.length;x++){
        var domino = player1Hand[x].toString();
        if(domino == "6,6"){
            $("#player1").addClass("first")
        };
        var src = ' src =images/Dominos/['+domino+'].png>';
        $('#player1 #hand').append('<img class = "domino" id ='+domino+src);
    };
    for(x = 0; x < player2Hand.length;x++){
        var domino = player2Hand[x].toString();
        if(domino == "6,6"){
            $("#player2").addClass("first")
        };
        var src = ' src =images/Dominos/['+domino+'].png>';
        $('#player2 #hand').append('<img class = "domino" id ='+domino+src);
    };
    for(x = 0; x < player3Hand.length;x++){
        var domino = player3Hand[x].toString();
        if(domino == "6,6"){
            $("#player3").addClass("first")
        };
        var src = ' src =images/Dominos/['+domino+'].png>';
        $('#player3 #hand').append('<img id ='+domino+src);
    };
    for(x = 0; x < player4Hand.length;x++){
        var domino = player4Hand[x].toString();
        if(domino == "6,6"){
            $("#player4").addClass("first")
        };
        var src = ' src =images/Dominos/['+domino+'].png>';
        $('#player4 #hand').append('<img id ='+domino+src);
    };
}


var choseFirstPlayer = function(){
    //console.log("I def shouldnt be here");
    if($("#player1").hasClass('first')){
        return "player1";
    }else if ($("#player2").hasClass('first')){
        return "player2";
    }else if($("#player3").hasClass('first')){
        return "player3";
    }else{
        return "player4";
    };
}

var playTurn = function(player){
    player = choseNextPlayer(player);
    $('#'+player+" #hand img").click(function(){
        var dominoSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var dominoNumber = $(this).attr('id');
        addDominoToBoard(dominoSrc,dominoNumber);
        $(this).remove();
        //console.log("This is the player after calling choseNextPlayer. This should be the same as the next player:"+player);
        playTurn(player);
    });

}

var choseNextPlayer = function(player){
    //console.log("This is the player at the beginning of choseNextPlayer:"+player);
    if(player == "player1"){
        //console.log("This is the previous player in choseNextPlayer. Should be the same as the player above:" + player);
        //console.log("This is the next player. Should follow the sequence" + "player2");
        $("#player1").hide();
        $("#player2").show();
        return "player2";
    }else if(player == "player2"){
        //console.log("This is the previous player in choseNextPlayer. Should be the same as the player above:" + player);
        //console.log("This is the next player. Should follow the sequence" + "player3");
        $("#player2").hide();
        $("#player3").show();
        return "player3";
    }else if(player == "player3"){
        //console.log("This is the previous player in choseNextPlayer. Should be the same as the player above:" + player);
        //console.log("This is the next player. Should follow the sequence" + "player4");
        $("#player3").hide();
        $("#player4").show();
        return "player4";
    }else{
        //console.log("This is the previous player in choseNextPlayer. Should be the same as the player above:" + player);
        //console.log("This is the next player. Should follow the sequence" + "player1");
        $("#player4").hide();
        $("#player1").show();
        return "player1";
    };
}

var checkGame = function(){
    return true;
}

var addDominoToBoard = function(dominoSrc,dominoNumber){
        $("#board #notPlaced").append("<img id =" + dominoNumber + " src ="+dominoSrc+">");
        drawDominoOnBoard(dominoNumber);
}

var drawDominoOnBoard = function(initalXposition,initalYposition,dominoNumber){
    var initalXposition = ($(window).width()/2) + "px";
    var initalYposition = ($(window).height()/2 -100) + "px";
    var domino = $("#board #notPlaced img");
    domino.css({"position": "absolute", "top": initalYposition, "left": initalXposition});
    var domino2 = domino.clone();
    $("#board #placed").append(domino2);
    domino.remove();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width() - $(window).width()/10; 
    var windowHeight = $(window).height() - $(window).height()/6;
    var gameOn = true;
    $("#board img").css({"width":windowWidth.toString(),"height":windowHeight.toString()}).hide();
    $("#pressed").hide();
    $("#notPressed").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $("#pressed").show();
    });
    $("#pressed").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $("#board img").show("slow",function(){
                loadGame();
                //console.log("Here again");
                var player = choseFirstPlayer();
                $('#'+player+" #hand img").click(function(){
                    //console.log("I should not be here");
                    var dominoSrc = $(this).attr('src');
                    var dominoNumber = $(this).attr('id');
                    addDominoToBoard(dominoSrc,dominoNumber);
                    $(this).remove();
                    playTurn(player);
                });
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I looked quickly at your code, but first did you check if your 'click' event listener added via jQuery is not added multiple times to your "#playerID #hand img" elements ? I'm not sure with jQuery remove your listener when you remove your elements from the DOM. Also your CSS selectors are little confusing, your are using IDs in a non unique manner: why use "#hand" and not ".hand".

Comment: and i think you're experiencing lags with your code because it is too DOM bound, not that you're doing too much DOM manipulation but your code relies too much on the DOM, in fact the 'state' of your game seems to lie in your DOM and not in your javascript code. It is much more expensive to query the DOM than using directly javascript, per instance you have too much code relying on jQuery selectors to retrieve elements even when you had already retrieved those elements before, maybe you should keep references to them instead

Comment: Thank you for your response. After doing some research on DOM manipulation, I came across this article http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/ which reiterated what you said. However, I found that what was really causing my program to lag was the addDominoToBoard(dominoSrc,dominoNumber) function in my playTurn function. Does anyone have any thoughts on a better way of refreshing the board / placing the dominos on the board. It seems messing with the css as well as the HTML is very costly.

Comment: FYI, jQuery lets you specify multiple selectors in one string: `$("#player2, #player3, #player4").hide()` for instance.

Comment: since you're looking for performance you should resolve your DOM (CSS, HTML..) issues. Stop using $ for everything keep references, and since it seems that you're using a lot of ID selectors, well these you should not retrieve them everytime you need them from the DOM. If you want to insert an image element, use the Image constructor or document.createElement it is much more efficient, reuse your images, you're creating new ones at each turn

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to thank KKetch for making me realize that I was doing a bunch of unnecessary DOM manipulations. After doing more research on jQuery, I realized that it is much better to declare variables instead of constantly getting HTML elements. However, that did not solve my lag problem. I solved my lag problem by eliminating the recursion and using events handlers. My solution was to rely on hiding and showing the hands on the screen. My game loop is self implied by the user being on the web page itself. The solution is below for anyone interested and if you want to keep track of this project, here is the link to the github page. Thanks once again.

Link: 
https://github.com/aneurycasado/Dominos-Para-Los-Dominicanos

Solution:

```
domino00 = new Image(); 
domino00.src = "images/Dominos/[0,0].png"
domino01 = new Image(); 
domino01.src = "images/Dominos/[0,1].png"
domino02 = new Image(); 
domino02.src = "images/Dominos/[0,2].png"
domino03 = new Image(); 
domino03.src = "images/Dominos/[0,3].png"
domino04 = new Image(); 
domino04.src = "images/Dominos/[0,4].png"
domino05 = new Image(); 
domino05.src = "images/Dominos/[0,5].png"
domino06 = new Image(); 
domino06.src = "images/Dominos/[0,6].png"
domino11 = new Image(); 
domino11.src = "images/Dominos/[1,1].png"
domino12 = new Image(); 
domino12.src = "images/Dominos/[1,2].png"
domino13 = new Image(); 
domino13.src = "images/Dominos/[1,3].png"
domino14 = new Image(); 
domino14.src = "images/Dominos/[1,4].png"
domino15 = new Image(); 
domino15.src = "images/Dominos/[1,5].png"
domino16 = new Image(); 
domino16.src = "images/Dominos/[1,6].png"
domino22 = new Image(); 
domino22.src = "images/Dominos/[2,2].png"
domino23 = new Image(); 
domino23.src = "images/Dominos/[2,3].png"
domino24 = new Image(); 
domino24.src = "images/Dominos/[2,4].png"
domino25 = new Image(); 
domino25.src = "images/Dominos/[2,5].png"
domino26 = new Image(); 
domino26.src = "images/Dominos/[2,6].png"
domino33 = new Image(); 
domino33.src = "images/Dominos/[3,3].png"
domino34 = new Image(); 
domino34.src = "images/Dominos/[3,4].png"
domino35 = new Image(); 
domino35.src = "images/Dominos/[3,5].png"
domino36 = new Image(); 
domino36.src = "images/Dominos/[3,6].png"
domino44 = new Image(); 
domino44.src = "images/Dominos/[4,4].png"
domino45 = new Image(); 
domino45.src = "images/Dominos/[4,5].png"
domino46 = new Image(); 
domino46.src = "images/Dominos/[4,6].png"
domino55 = new Image(); 
domino55.src = "images/Dominos/[5,5].png"
domino56 = new Image(); 
domino56.src = "images/Dominos/[5,6].png"
domino66 = new Image(); 
domino66.src = "images/Dominos/[6,6].png"

dominoImages = [ domino00,domino01,domino02,domino03,domino04,domino05,domino06,
                 domino11,domino12,domino13,domino14,domino15,domino16,
                 domino22,domino23,domino24,domino25,domino26,
                 domino33,domino34,domino35,domino36,
                 domino44,domino45,domino46,
                 domino55,domino56,
                 domino66
               ]


var drawDominoOnBoard = function(initalXposition,initalYposition,dominoNumber){
    var initalXposition = ($(window).width()/2) + "px";
    var initalYposition = ($(window).height()/2 -100) + "px";
    var domino = $("#board #notPlaced img");
    domino.css({"position": "absolute", "top": initalYposition, "left": initalXposition});
    var domino2 = domino.clone();
    $("#board #placed").append(domino2);
    domino.remove();
}

var playTurn = function(player,  player1, player2,
                        player3, player4, dominosPlaced){
    player = choseNextPlayer(player,player1,player2,player3,player4);
    $('#'+player+" #hand img").click(function(){
        var domino = $(this);
        addDominoToBoard(domino,dominosPlaced);
        $(this).remove();
        $(this).unbind("click");
        playTurn(player,player1,player2,player3,player4,dominosPlaced);
    }); 
}

var choseNextPlayer = function(player,player1,player2,player3,player4){
    //console.log("This is the player at the beginning of choseNextPlayer:"+player);
    if(player == "player1"){
        //console.log("This is the previous player in choseNextPlayer. Should be the same as the player above:" + player);
        //console.log("This is the next player. Should follow the sequence" + "player2");
        player1.hide();
        player2.show();
        return "player2";
    }else if(player == "player2"){
        //console.log("This is the previous player in choseNextPlayer. Should be the same as the player above:" + player);
        //console.log("This is the next player. Should follow the sequence" + "player3");
        player2.hide();
        player3.show();
        return "player3";
    }else if(player == "player3"){
        //console.log("This is the previous player in choseNextPlayer. Should be the same as the player above:" + player);
        //console.log("This is the next player. Should follow the sequence" + "player4");
        player3.hide();
        player4.show();
        return "player4";
    }else{
        //console.log("This is the previous player in choseNextPlayer. Should be the same as the player above:" + player);
        //console.log("This is the next player. Should follow the sequence" + "player1");
        player4.hide();
        player1.show();
        return "player1";
    };
}

var addDominoToBoard = function(domino,dominoPlaced){
    var dominoClone = domino.clone();
    dominoPlaced.append(dominoClone);
    drawDominoOnBoard(dominoPlaced);
}

var choseFirstPlayer = function(player1,player2,player3,player4){
    //console.log("I def shouldnt be here");
    if(player1.find("#hand").hasClass('first')){
        player1.show();
        return "player1";
    }else if (player2.find("#hand").hasClass('first')){
        player2.show();
        return "player2";
    }else if(player3.find("#hand").hasClass('first')){
        player3.show();
        return "player3";
    }else{
        player4.show();
        return "player4";
    };
}

var hideHands = function(player1,player2,player3,player4){
    player1.hide();
    player2.hide();
    player3.hide();
    player4.hide();
}

var randomInt = function(number){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*number);
}

var makeHand = function(player){
    var hand = [];
    var player = $(player);
    var src = domino66.src
    for(x = 0;x<7;x++){
        var ranInt = randomInt(dominoImages.length);
        var domino = dominoImages[ranInt];
        if(domino.src == src){
            player.addClass("first");
        }
        player.append(domino);
        dominoImages.splice(ranInt,1);
    }
    return hand;
}

var hideHands = function(player1,player2,player3,player4){
    player1.hide();
    player2.hide();
    player3.hide();
    player4.hide();
}

var loadGame = function(){
    makeHand("#player1 #hand");
    makeHand("#player2 #hand");
    makeHand("#player3 #hand");
    makeHand("#player4 #hand");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadGame();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width() - $(window).width()/10; 
    var windowHeight = $(window).height() - $(window).height()/6;
    var gameOn = true;
    var boardImg = $("#board img");
    var dominosPlaced = $("#board #placed");
    var pressed = $("#pressed");
    var notPressed = $("#notPressed");
    var player1 = $("#player1");
    var player2 = $("#player2");
    var player3 = $("#player3");
    var player4 = $("#player4");
    hideHands(player1,player2,player3,player4);
    var player = ""
    boardImg.css({"width":windowWidth.toString(),"height":windowHeight.toString()}).hide();
    pressed.hide();
    notPressed.hover(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        pressed.show();
    });
    pressed.click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("slow",function(){
            boardImg.show("slow",function(){            
                player = choseFirstPlayer(player1,player2,player3,player4);
            });
        });
    });
    $("#player1 #hand img").click(function(){
                    var domino = $(this);
                    addDominoToBoard(domino,dominosPlaced);
                    $(this).remove();
                    player = choseNextPlayer(player,player1,player2,player3,player4)
    }); 
    $("#player2 #hand img").click(function(){
                    var domino = $(this);
                    addDominoToBoard(domino,dominosPlaced);
                    $(this).remove();
                    player = choseNextPlayer(player,player1,player2,player3,player4)
    }); 
    $("#player3 #hand img").click(function(){
                    var domino = $(this);
                    addDominoToBoard(domino,dominosPlaced);
                    $(this).remove();
                    player = choseNextPlayer(player,player1,player2,player3,player4)
    }); 
    $("#player4 #hand img").click(function(){
                    var domino = $(this);
                    addDominoToBoard(domino,dominosPlaced);
                    $(this).remove();
                    player = choseNextPlayer(player,player1,player2,player3,player4)
    }); 
});
```